# How to let more inactive run tool tabs not auto-close in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

There is just one inactive open run tool tabs allowed at any time.

If my run task is not actively running any other new run task will close the inactive tab.

Is there a configuration possible to allow more open inactive tabs?

I know i can pin them. But that's not what i really want.

---

I can see the same behaviour on my IDE's PhpStorm and Webstorm, currently both at version 2021.3.1

Comment: If you have no Run tabs pinned, each new launch should replace the existing tab instead of keeping two. What run configuration are you using exactly?

Comment: @EugeneMorozov you are completely right. had in mind that there would be two inactive tabs possible. i edited my question.

Comment: In 2022.1 EAP, [you will be able](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156517#focus=Comments-27-5403063.0-0) to configure the tabs to be pinned by default, but unfortunately, there's no way to make them go when a certain limit is reached